# Substrings using regex grouping in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, extract

I want to retrieve substrings from a string using regex.

Just for info : These string values are subjects in mails

```
String1 = "Acceptance :DT_Ext_0062-12_012ed2 [Describe]"

string2 = "Acceptance : DT_Ext_0062-12_012 (ed.2) , Describe"

string3 = "Acceptance of : DT_Ext_0062-12_012 (ed.2) , Describe to me"
```

Substrings:

```
sub1 = Acceptance            <Mail Type : like Reject or Accept>
sub2 = DT_Ext_0062-12_012    <ID : unique identifier>
sub3 = ed2                   <Edition of mail, like : ed1, ed2, ed3 ...so on>
sub4 = Describe              <Description of the mail>
```

How can i write regex(either seperately or one regex for both) for the above two strings to get the same output.

I think match groups can be used to retrieve the data. But i am quite new to regex.

Comment: what is the language ?

Comment: I forget to mention...it's C#

Comment: Can you show more sample data ? What the rules for separating sub2 from sub3 ?

Comment: @Sniffer : The above strings are the subject line in mails. As such there are no rules for seperating the substrings. This is the major problem that i was also facing. But yes some words will be mandatory in the string, like : DT_Ext, ed. But the Acceptance and describe can be any value as string.

Comment: Is there a colon `:` after the Acceptance string always ? Is there always some sort of spacing between sub3 and sub4 ?

Comment: @Sniffer: ":" is mandatory - yes. Spaces will be as i mentioned in the example. I have also edited my question, just to give a bit more info, although not beneficiary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// string strTargetString = @"Acceptance :DT_Ext_0062-12_012ed2 [Describe]";
// string strTargetString = @"Acceptance : DT_Ext_0062-12_012 (ed.2) , Describe";
string strTargetString = @"Acceptance of : DT_Ext_0062-12_012 (ed.2) , Describe to me";

 const string strRegex = @"\.*:\s*(DT_Ext_\d{4}-\d{2}_\d{3})\s*\W*(ed)\.?(\d+)(\W*[,])?(.*)";


RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);


foreach(Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
    if(myMatch.Success)
    {
        // Add your code here
        var value = new {
            Value1 = myMatch.Groups[1].Value,
            Value2 = myMatch.Groups[2].Value,
            Value3 = myMatch.Groups[3].Value,
            Value4 = myMatch.Groups[5].Value,
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Got the two substrings correct. Thanks. Although, Acceptance and Describe are not the keywords. They can be any value in string.

Comment: I just realised that you edited your question a little bit before I posted my answer, so I couldn't know exactly what you needed. If my answerr was helpful please mark it as the correct answer and upvote it, please. Thanks

Comment: i actually did not get what i wanted, so cannot mark it as my answer. But yes it helped me, i would love to upvote it, but i myself do not have much reputation to do that.

Comment: Suppose if the string is "Acceptance of : DT_Ext_0062-12_012 (ed.2) , Describe to me", as i said Acceptance and Describe can be any value of string. Still not getting the desired output. May be there is some issue with spaces.

Comment: You have to be specific when you make a question, specially related to regular expressions. We cannot guess what will be the input, you need to give us a few examples and describe what could come in the string. I'll change my answer to match the other string as well.

Comment: OK...but that is the bigger challenge. Anyways. Can the solution be:
Group1 - All characters before ":" Group2&3 - OK Group4 - All characters after ","

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I tried myself after you provided me a sloution and the following regex will work on String2 but i am getting extra "]" in string1. Regex : `@"(.*)\s*:\s*(DT_Ext_\d{4}-\d{2}_\d{3})\s*\W*(ed)\.?(\d+)\W*(.*)\W*"`. See if you can help me on string1 also. Thanks.

Comment: Sub1 is not coming, coz you missed braces for group1. Also Sub3 got broken and Sub4 is also not good. :( You can check what i posted in the comment above. It is same that you posted earlier just with some smaller change. All what i need is to remove "]" from last in sub4 for string1. hope you understand.

Comment: I have changed the regex and also the foreach loop, it's working fine for the 3 expressions. All characters after the `,` are being grouped, as you requested before. Now you can do a little bit of work to get rid of the `[]`s